# Is the date_range_start parameter based on the entry date?

Tags: solspace-calendar

I assumed the tag would be based on the start date of an event, however I have this code

`{exp:calendar:events orderby="event_start_date" author_id="{member_id}"}`

which shows all entries. When I add the date_range_start parameter

`{exp:calendar:events orderby="event_start_date" author_id="{member_id}" date_range_start="today"}`

no entries appear, even though there are two events with start dates in May, 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking to order events in chronological order. In that case, you must use **`{exp:calendar:cal}`** and not `{exp:calendar:events}`. {exp:calendar:cal} is the only tag that will order events in chronological order (and take overlapping events/occurrences, etc into consideration), as well as calculate which events/occurrences fit inside the time frame set up in the `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` parameters.

★ The following is a must read for further details on deciding which tag to use for your purpose: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Also, in your example {exp:calendar:events} simply reads date_range_start="" and compares it to the date data set up in the event entry form (not the EE entry_date). Further, using date_range_start="today" but not specifying date_range_end="" means date_range_end will default to "today". You would need something like `date_range_end="+6 months"`